# How to select distinct records from individual column in sql table

Tags: sql, datatable, distinct

I want to retrieve distinct rows from each column in this sql table

My table

```
1    Apple
2    Banana
3    Apple
2    Apple
1    Orange
```

I want the result like this:

```
1   Apple
2   Banana
3   Orange
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT` on each column. You will get 2 resultsets. Then do `UNION ALL` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` to combine the 2 resultsets into 1.

Comment: i have tried select distinct [Firstname] from data
union all
select distinct [Lastname] from data   ---- But the result came in single column ("Firstname") .... i want the result to be in two column

Comment: You need to **explain** the logic behind this - what do you want to do to go from the original data to the result? What's the thinking / rules behind this? Don't just dump two set of data on us and let *us* wonder what might be going on here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it

```
select *,row=rank() over(order by name) from  (SELECT distinct name FROM abc) as cte
```

or

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT distinct name FROM abc
) 
select *,row=rank() over(order by name) from cte
```

Output

```
| row       | Name |
|-----------|----------|
|         1 |    Apple |
|         2 |   Banana |
|         3 |   Orange |
```

Comment: may i know what is cte

Comment: cte is temprery table ,, we can store the value in this only on Runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can get the distinct names by doing:

```
select distinct name
from table t;
```

You can add the first column by doing:

```
select row_number() over (order by name) as id, name
from (select distinct name
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Most databases support the ANSI standard row number.  You haven't tagged this with the database, so that is the most general solution.

EDIT:

Oh, you want two columns each with values.  I would approach this as a `full outer join`:

```
select nu.num, na.name
from (select num, row_number() over (order by num) as seqnum
      from table
      group by num
     ) nu full outer join
     (select name, row_number() over (order by name) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by name
     ) na
     on nu.seqnum = na.seqnum;
```

Each subquery enumerates the values in each column.  The `full outer join` makes sure that you have values even when they are missing on one side or the other.

Comment: How would you actually retrieve the data from OP's first column, and work towards the asked for result? And how to cater for differing number of entries in the respective columns?

Comment: Abecee . . . I see.  I think I originally misunderstood the question, but added another answer.  I still don't know which interpretation is correct (note that the title uses "column" in the singular).

Comment: GordonLinoff - Suggested edit to drop `select (` from `select (select` from the `outer join`'s second part (and the unused `t` alias) was rejected…

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept.
Tested on Oracle 11.2

```
WITH
MyTable (firstName, lastName) AS (
  SELECT '1', 'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', 'Banana' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '3', 'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2', 'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '4', 'Apple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', 'Orange' FROM DUAL),
Ranked AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    firstName
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY firstName) AS fnRnk
    , lastName
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY lastName) AS lnRnk
  FROM MyTable  
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT R1.firstName, R2.lastName FROM Ranked R1 FULL OUTER JOIN Ranked R2 ON R1.fnRnk = R2.lnRnk ORDER BY lastName NULLS LAST, firstName
;
```

Returns

```
| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
|-----------|----------|
|         1 |    Apple |
|         2 |   Banana |
|         3 |   Orange |
|         4 |   (null) |
```

Added a row to the original data to demonstrate columns of different length.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a348d/3/0)